# Why can not I associate a variable in a request that returns more than one field?

Tags: mysql, procedure, mysql-error-1222

This procedure bellow returns

> Error Code: 1222: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `dev_getDashBoard`(cognito VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
   DECLARE id_user,team_last INT;

   SELECT ct.hasInvoice,ct.currentCredits,ct.hasPremium,u.lastTeam INTO team_last  FROM configTeam ct
   INNER JOIN users u ON u.lastTeam = ct.team_id
   WHERE u.identityId = cognito COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci LIMIT 1

   CALL otherProcedure(team_last);
END
```

The sql always return one row. Why mysql return the error?

Comment: here you are assigning multiple columns into one variable team_last .That's why its throwing error

Answer (score 0):

Remove the other columns from the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT u.lastTeam INTO team_last
FROM configTeam ct INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON u.lastTeam = ct.team_id
WHERE u.identityId = cognito COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: it's not variables. it is columns